# php code execution without quotes

Tags: php, security

I am writing a POC of a php code execution vulnerability, but i am having a filter that i can't bypass,simply i can execute any function just without using quotes `` " ' ` `` .
I tried to execute some codes like `dirscan(getcwd())` and `phpinfo()` and it worked
but I couldn't find any function to use it for encoding and decoding numbers 
to strings or any other ways to use `$_REQUEST` and `$_SERVER` vars

there is the old `base64_decode` but it need quotes too.

so any thoughts to execute any code i want ?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: simply i want to use something like eval('evilcode') to prove that it is an exploitable bug , only i can't use quotes so i was thinking of some php function to convert numbers to a string and excute it 
eval(number2text(11111111111111)) and it will give me <?php echo 'hi'; ?>

Comment: So you are assuming that there's a bug in PHP, but you can't find it? And also you think that if a script runs eval on something that comes from the user that's a bug in the language, and not in the logic? The man page states what are the risks of using it very clearly http://php.net/eval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a form with an input like:

```
<input type=text name=1>
```

Then the PHP script can do:

```
eval($_REQUEST[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code can generate a string without using any quotes:

```
$array = [ 0x48, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x4c, 0x4f ];

$string = array_reduce($array, function ($a, $b) { return $a . chr($b); });

echo $string; // Prints "HELLO"
```